# Clean urls in php with / at the end

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, clean-urls

I am trying to figure those clean urls out again.
I am trying to "convert"

http://www.website.com/videos.php?url=testurl

into

http://www.website.com/videos/testurl/

All of that works fine as long as I write the url without the / at the end.
But for me it is really important to have the / at the end.

Here is my htaccess:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/$ $1.php
RewriteRule videos/(.*)/?$ /videos.php?url=$1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^videos/([^/]+)/?$ videos.php?url=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion. I think we are getting closer. Now the get result is:
testurl.php
Is there any way i can change this to just testurl trhough the htaccess?

Comment: What URL did you enter to test? also try updated rules.

Comment: I tested it with www.domain.com/videos/testurl/

Comment: I am sorry buddy. I have had some other stuff in there. After i deleted it it works like a charm. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [rtrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php):

```
$url = 'http://www.website.com/videos/testurl/';
$url = rtrim($url, '/');
```

Comment: Thank you for that answer. I noticed that the get wil return 
testurl.php/testurl
I know that i could use rtrim but i was wondering if there is a way that i will just get the return of testurl instead of the url above?